# Why new ram is not supporting in my motherboard Asus Motherboard P5G41T-M LX

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

My motherboard is - Asus P5G41T-M LX. I had a 2GB RAM. It works fine. Now I have bought a 4GB RAM. When I put it in motherboard the PC starts but doesn't show anything in the monitor. If remove then works fine. It means only with the previous RAM it works fine. But the new RAM doesn't work at all. Plugging in only the new RAM doesn't work. Plugging in both the new RAM and old RAM doesn't work. MY PC is Dual Core. I have added the details below. Can anybody please help me on this please?

Details ::

[image]

here is some information with 2GB previous RAM using CPU-Z software::

[image]
[image]
[image]

New RAM info ::
`ADATA
AD3U1333W4G9-S
DDR3 1333(9) 4GX8 U-DIMM
10242459`

Comment: Are you saying, there is no configuration that works now, if so you should say that.  however you said it currently is not clear.

Comment: don't understand what configuration you are talking. Only with 2GB the pc shows screen in the monitor. But if 4GB added pc starts fans are running but the screen is blank. Also the RAM is being heated. But don't show anything in the screen. Can you help ?

Comment: "If I add with the previous RAM, or without the previous RAM doesn't start." - This statement is not clear.

Comment: it means only with the previous RAM it works fine. But only with new one, or new one + previous one = doesn't work.

Comment: You should edit your question to make that clear.  What you have now is confusing.

Comment: I edit the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: What voltage does your new memory require?  What voltage does your old memory require?  What frequency does each module run at?  Edit your question to include this information.

Comment: how to know that? can you please tell? I don't know

Comment: Look up the specifications each module.

Comment: Also who is the manufacturer of both RAM modules? The voltage and frequency is usually printed on a sticker on the RAM. The frequency will be xxxx MHZ and the voltage will be xx volts.

Comment: give me sometimes. I am giving you the image of the two RAM

Comment: Your new memory default frequency is to fast for your hardware.

Comment: what can i do now

Comment: @SumonBappi - Purchase memory compatible with your system

Comment: My motherboard is 41 model. It will not support more than 2GB on a slot. So I changed my new RAM from 4GB to 2GB. Thanks guys for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can check
Are you sure your new RAM isn't dead? (You might have gotten faulty RAMsticks).
Check RAM slots.
Take the old RAM and try out different slots on the motherboard to see if it works.
See if the new and old RAM have different clock speed then you will also need to under clock the one with more clock speed to match them if you want to use the new and old RAM together.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Adata and Corsair ram, both didn't work so I tried G-Skill Ripsaws DDR3 1600 I had in another computer and it worked. Its a real picky board.